# Using both closetag.js & closebrackets.js in Codemirror on same line

Tags: javascript, codemirror

so I'm implementing the Codemirror library with a textarea so I can autoclose HTML tags and brackets - {}, (), []. However, I've noticed when using them that they don't work together on the same line.

Say I'm typing out a tag like this:

```
<div></div>
```

It autocloses and the cursor is in the middle between the two tags above.
But if I try to add a bracket:

```
<div>{</div>
```

It won't close because of how closebrackets.js works. On it's own line it works.
I found a cheap hack where inside closetag.js (Line 80), you can add a space, changing it from:

```
text: ">" + (indent ? "\n\n" : "") + "</" + tagName + ">",
```

To

```
text: ">" + (indent ? "\n\n" : " ") + "</" + tagName + ">",
```

And then the tags close like this:

```
<div> </div>
```

But then it's kind of annoying and ugly because you have this extra space, just to make it a little more fluent.

Any idea on how to implement both of these on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

CodeMirror's closebrackets addon copies Sublime Text's behavior in that it'll only autoclose when the cursor is in front of another closing character or whitespace. I'm not particularly attached to this behavior, but I also don't want to make random changes based on a single use case. Is there a precedent for other behavior? If so, how exacly does this behavior work? Opening brackets between HTML tags does not sound like an incredibly common use case.